# React node-modules

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules

Sure, there are plenty of tutorials out there that tell the user which modules to import within a react application.

My question is, without being told which imports to use, are there any resources out there that break the long list of packages included within the node_modules folder in a react application down into sections based on their functionality?

My current solution is to go through each package and search for it in the NPM registry to see if it is something that will be useful to me.

Comment: All packages installed(in `node_modules`) when using `create-react-app` are needed when creating a react app. Any external packages like react-navigation can we examined by checkout out their github package or website.

Comment: You just need at the very least `react` and `react-dom` in your *package.json* to start with. See any boilerplate react project in github. Here's an example https://blog.usejournal.com/setting-up-react-webpack-4-babel-7-from-scratch-2019-b771dca2f637

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know which packages are necessary for React development, you only need `react` and `react-dom`, as @dmitryro points out. `react` is for building components, using hooks, JSX, etc., and `react-dom` is for rendering components.

Those have some dependencies, though, so if you look at the node_modules folder you will see a lot more than just `react` and `react-dom`.